# What does y argument do in chisq.test in R?

Tags: r, chi-squared-test

The `chisq.test` function in R includes a `y =` argument, which is to `NULL` by default. The help page doesn't explain what this argument does, and playing round with numbers doesn't give any clues, for example all these give exactly same results:

```
chisq.test(x=c(20, 10, 5, 3, 2, 1, 0), y  = 100:106)
chisq.test(x=c(20, 10, 5, 3, 2, 1, 0), y  = 0:6)
chisq.test(x=c(20, 10, 5, 3, 2, 1, 0), y  = 5:11)
```

Comment: Actually, the help very clearly states what happens when you specify `y`: "*[...] Otherwise, `x` and `y` must be vectors or factors of the same length; cases with missing values are removed, the objects are coerced to factors, and the contingency table is computed from these. Then Pearson's chi-squared test is performed of the null hypothesis that the joint distribution of the cell counts in a 2-dimensional contingency table is the product of the row and column marginals.*"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. It does a chi-square test of independence for the cross-classification of factors `x` and `y`, i.e. the results of `table(x,y)`.

```
> x = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
> y = c(0,2,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,2,2,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1)
> chisq.test(x,y)

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  x and y
X-squared = 1.8333, df = 2, p-value = 0.3998

> chisq.test(table(x,y))

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  table(x, y)
X-squared = 1.8333, df = 2, p-value = 0.3998
```

Comment: luciano: It might be worth trying Russ' example yourself, but also look at `table(x,y)` to see the actual table it's working with.