Why do I get a large difference between the p-value of a Chi-square test and the p-value of a KS test?
Introduction. I have data, representing the number of mammals, in a certain  geographical region. I show here an example of data (please see the code below for more information):
>> r1

500, 1700, 0, 600, 400, 100, 200, 400, 9700, 4300, 100, etc..

I want to compare the distributions of two groups of mammals, by using the two-sample Chi-squared test and KS test.
I was able to reproduce something similar to my case, where the p-value of the Chi-squared test was lower than the significance level $\alpha = 0.05$, while the p-value of the KS test was quite high (therefore, the two p-values were very different):
rng(0,'twister');
a = 0;
b = 100;
bw = 100;
r1 = (b-a).*round(lognrnd(1,1,1000,1)) + a;
r2 = (b-a).*round(lognrnd(0.88,1.1,1000,1)) + a;
hold on
h1 = histogram(r1,'BinWidth',bw);
h2 = histogram(r2,'BinWidth',bw);
last_bin = 20;
[~,p_CS,~] = chi2gof(1:length(h1.Values(1:last_bin)), 'Expected', h2.Values(1:last_bin), 'Frequency', h1.Values(1:last_bin), 'EMin', 0)
[~,p_KS,~] = kstest2(r1,r2)
xlim([0 2000])

With this resulting plot and p-values:

p_CS =
   0.00029734

p_KS =
      0.71613

Code explanation.

I created the raw datasets r1 and r2 from log-norm distributions, with $\mu = 1$ and $\sigma = 1$ for the first log-norm distribution, and with $\mu = 0.88$ and $\sigma = 1.1$ for the second log-norm distribution
h1.Values and h1.Values are the counts, i.e. the frequency of  the raw datasets r1 and r2.
As we can see h1.Values and h1.Values are outputs of the function histogram, and they are calculated by that function, which also plots the histograms that we can see.
Therefore the functions histograms take the raw datasets r1 and r2 and the additional argument BinWidth, that I set as 100, to count the frequency of the values in r1 and r2, and,  consequently, to plot the corresponding histograms.
chi2gof is the name of the Matlab function which performs a Chi-square test, either 1-sample one or 2-sample one. About the arguments of that function: the first one is a dummy vector of numbers. You can use whatever you want there (but it has to have the same size/length of h1.Values or of h1.Values). It is just to make work that function, but it does not enter in the calculation of the Chi-square test. So, no worries about the first argument.
The important inputs of the chi2gof function are the second and third arguments, i.e. the 'Expected' and the 'Frequency' arguments, i.e. the binned values of the first and second datasets/distributions respectively. About the last argument, 'Emin', if we specify EMin as 0, we prevent the combining of bins.
the kstest2 takes the raw datasets r1 and r2 as inputs.
Please note that the inputs of the Chi-squared test are binned data, i.e. h1.Values and h2.Values, while the inputs of the KS test are the raw data, i.e. r1 and r2.

Question. Why do I get a large difference between the p-value of a Chi-square test and the p-value of a KS test?
Additional comments. I understand that the Chi-squared test "measures" the squared differences among the number of observations that fall in bin "i" (first dataset/distribution) and  the number of observations expected to fall in bin "i" (second dataset/distribution), while the Kolmogorov–Smirnov test "measures" the max distance between the two ECDFs.
Said that, the KS test "tends to be more sensitive near the center of the distribution than at the tails", and, but just my interpretation, it looks like the Chi-squared test is sensitive to each "part" of the distributions, since the squared differences between observed and expected values are calculated for all the bins of the distributions.
Extra content about the chi2gof function of Matlab, which performs the Chi-squared test.
This is a way to show that what I used in my above example to perform the Chi-squared test, i.e.
[~,p_CS,~] = chi2gof(1:length(h1.Values(1:last_bin)), 'Expected', h2.Values(1:last_bin), 'Frequency', h1.Values(1:last_bin), 'EMin', 0)

leads to the same results of a "manual" calculation (for both the p-value and the test statistic).
This is a simple example, which can be tested with other programming languages, like Python or R.
By using the chi2gof function:
% inputs, x = observed binned data, y = expected binned data
x = [41 22 11 10 9 5 2 3 2];
y = [38.052 24.2655 15.4665 9.8595 6.2895 4.011 2.562 1.6275 2.8665]; 

% Chi-squared test
[~, p_value, stats]=chi2gof(1:length(x), 'Expected', y, 'Frequency', x, 'EMin', 0)

we get the following results:
p_value =

      0.79051


stats = 

  struct with fields:

    chi2stat: 4.6864
          df: 8
       edges: [1 1.8889 2.7778 3.6667 4.5556 5.4444 6.3333 7.2222 8.1111 9]
           O: [41 22 11 10 9 5 2 3 2]
           E: [38.052 24.265 15.466 9.8595 6.2895 4.011 2.562 1.6275 2.8665]

By using a "manual" calculation, with the same exact inputs, i.e. "x" (observed binned data) and "y" (expected binned data) arrays:
% Chi-squared test
chi2 = sum(((x-y).^2)./y);       % <-- chi-square value
df = length(x)-1;                % <-- degrees of freedom
p = chi2cdf(chi2,df,'upper');    % <-- p-value calculated from the chi-square distribution with "df" degrees of freedom
table([chi2; df; p],'RowNames',{'chi-square','df','p-value'},'VariableNames',{'Stats'}) % <-- print the results in a table

we get the following results:
                   Stats 
                  _______

    chi-square     4.6864
    df                  8
    p-value       0.79051

We can see that we get the same p-value (i.e. 0.79051) and the same test statistic (i.e. 4.6864) with both methods.
Extra content after the answer of @EdM.
I run the @EdM code
## rm(list = ls())
## cat("\014")

## inputs
set.seed(0,kind="Mersenne-Twister")
a <- 0
b <- 100
r1 <- (b-a) * round(rlnorm(1000,1,1)) + a
r2 <- (b-a) * round(rlnorm(1000,.88,1.1)) + a
## truncate both at values of 2000, as in the question
r1trunc <- r1[r1<=2000]
r2trunc <- r2[r2<=2000]
## put into 20 bins, to match the question
## the results are factors
r1breaks <- cut(r1trunc,breaks=20)
r2breaks <- cut(r2trunc,breaks=20)
## summary() on a factor produces the count for each level
summary_r1breaks <- summary(r1breaks)
summary_r2breaks <- summary(r2breaks)
## this is the contingency table test
chisq.test(summary_r1breaks,summary_r2breaks)

## show me concisely summary_r1breaks and summary_r2breaks
table(summary_r1breaks)
table(summary_r2breaks)

Getting the @EdM results, obviously:
> chisq.test(summary_r1breaks,summary_r2breaks)

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  summary_r1breaks and summary_r2breaks
X-squared = 325, df = 306, p-value = 0.2178

Warning message:
In chisq.test(summary_r1breaks, summary_r2breaks) :
  Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
> 
> ## show me concisely "summary_r1breaks" and "summary_r2breaks"
> table(summary_r1breaks)
summary_r1breaks
  1   3   4   5   6   8  10  11  18  20  22  27  37  44  65  78 127 202 287 
  1   1   1   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1 
> table(summary_r2breaks)
summary_r2breaks
  1   2   4   6   7   8  11  12  13  19  30  33  49  51  64 124 171 348 
  1   1   1   1   1   2   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1 

It looks like that the equivalent function of the R's "chisq.test()", at least for this case, is the Matlab's "crosstab" function. Indeed, by using the same binned data of R, i.e. "summary_r1breaks" and "summary_r1breaks", as inputs for the crosstab function in Matlab:
summary_r1breaks = [1   3   4   5   6 6  8  10  11  18  20  22  27  37  44  65  78 127 202 287];
summary_r2breaks = [1   2   4   6   7   8 8 11  11  12  13  19  30  33  49  51  64 124 171 348];
[~,chi2stat,pval] = crosstab(summary_r1breaks,summary_r2breaks)

we get the same results for the p-value and the test statistic (even though I am not able to print/see the degrees of freedom):
chi2stat =
                       325
pval =
         0.217842215700274


This replaces a question which was closed and which you then deleted. You're allowed to do that, but this version doesn't help me at all. In your previous question you had as I understand it an explanation that you have counts of three mammal species in a series of years. Now the question is about "two groups of mammals", whatever that means. You're rightly concerned about what appear to be contradictory results although as stressed several times to you different results are unsurprising as different tests answer different questions.

In this example, one problem is that chi-square tests will depend on bin width, which you need to address. (I address it by never using chi-square tests unless the bins are already discrete and distinct values.) For your real data, if you're binning time series, there is likely to be a subtle problem if both tests assume independent values, but that is beyond my technical reach.

Your broad comparison about the sensitivity of KS and chi-square testing is on target and is a standard point confirmed in your previous thread, so why keep asking about it? You get to ask the questions, but why not give us a direct example using your real data?

Thanks a lot @NickCox, Yes, I deleted the previous questions since It started to be quite messy (but just my opinion), so I thought to have a fresh start again. Unfortunately, I cannot share too many details, but I might ask if some further details can be shared. However, my main concern was about the large discrepancy among p-values of different tests.

Yes, I understand that different tools give different results and answers. But, at this point, I think it is just my preconception that I think that, more or less, all the statistical tests should somehow agree. Instead, it looks like they can disagree in terms of p-vaules. Although those tests can give different p-values, still my brain continues to ask why? Which mechanisms lead to different p-values? How should I interpret these differences?

Also, I think, that from the math point of view, statistical tests should have explanations, since those tests have a math foundation, regardless the meaning of the numbers. The representation of those numbers should not affect the interpretation of the math results of the tests, as the p-values or the statistics of the tests. I feel that the knowledge of the meaning of the data is then a way to understand the statistics of the tests. But, it should be the opposite. Otherwise, why should we use statistics, i.e. math objects?

Thanks for the extra comments. Sorry, but I can't grasp quite what you're asking or expecting here. If you can't show your real data, then that is a bar to much help. Otherwise our comments are just repeating points that you appear to understand already. Reproducing your results may be possible for someone who uses R routinely, which I don't.  It usually be a biological surprise if counts of two mammal species followed exactly the same distribution if only because they would be expected in general to differ in level and spread, would it not?

I suggest you look carefully at the bin counts you're feeding to chi-square. It's division by small expected counts that drives up chi-square.

Uncommented code in a mystery language, an unlabelled histogram - too much trouble to work out what you in fact did. I note that (1) you appear to be rounding the data - if that produces ties they'll need to be properly dealt with in the K-S test; & (2) 'gof' (goodness of fit) in the chi-squared test function & 'Expected' in its arguments suggest you may not have correctly formulated a test of homogeneity.

I was guessing you're using R; my next guess is Matlab. This is of some importance insofar as not explaining the software you're using and using software which only a few people here use (and I do the same, by the way, as a Stata user) make it more difficult to follow or replicate what you've done.

@NickCox: Ideally everyone would explain what they're doing in English & Maths, with code just for reference & to aid replication. R users here can get away with almost bare code sometimes - but some are missing out on much-needed practice in statistical explanation, I feel.

@Scortchi-ReinstateMonica about (1) rounding the data is just to create artificial integer numbers, i.e. the input for statistical tests. They are quite similar to my real data. About (2) chi2gof is the name of the Matlab function to perform a Chi-sqaure test, either 1-samlpe one or 2-sample one. About the arguments of that function: the first one is a dummy vector of numbers. You can use whatever you want there. It is just to make work that function, but it does enter in the calculation of the Chi-sqaure test. So no worries about the first argument.

The real inputs of that functions are the second and third arguments, i.e. the 'Expected' and the 'frequency' arguments, i.e. the binned values of the first and second datasets/distributions respectively. About the last argument, 'Emin',  if we specify EMin as 0 we prevent the combining of bins (https://ch.mathworks.com/help/stats/chi2gof.html).

h1.Values and h1.Values are the counts, i.e. the frequency of  the raw datasets r1 and r2, that I created from log-norm distributions. As we can see h1.Values and h1.Values are outputs of the functions histograms, and they are calculated by that functions, which also plots the histograms that we can see. Therefore the functions histograms take the raw datasets r1 and r2and the additional argumentBinWidth, that I set as 100, to count the frequency of the values in r1andr2``, and,  consequently, to plot the corresponding histograms.

The matlab code is quite similar to the R one... nothing special, quite basic

Although my question will be likely kept closed, I still want to chase windmills :-)

The extra detail needs to be in the question, not in comments. From what you've said you're carrying out the chi-squared test incorrectly: the observed counts from the 1st data-set are not the expected values of counts from the 2nd data-set. And the K-S test is for continuous data - real data are of course always recorded to finite precision, but you need to check for ties.

Thanks @Scortchi - Reinstate Monica.... About the KS, yes I can check for ties (and maybe use another test - I guess - in case of ties)... About the chi-square test, that is a standard way to compare 2 sets of binned data... I do not know other ways to use that function, but I can double check with the MATLAB forums.... Probably the two words, Expected and Frequency, can be misleading

Thanks @NickCox for your suggestions... Probably the chi-squared test is not ideal/appropriate here (since it was designed for categorical data)... And... Yes, it is Matlab, but quite similar to R.. Thanks

And thanks to [I don't know who] who reopened the question

@Scortchi-ReinstateMonica, just a little doubt about your comment:
"the observed counts from the 1st data-set are not the expected values of counts from the 2nd data-set" If I want to use the Chi-sqaure test to compare two datasets/distributions, one dataset will play the role of observed counts/frequency, and the second dataset will play the role of expected counts/frequency. Right or wrong?

@Scortchi-ReinstateMonica - If right, then: "WE HYPOTHESISE that the observed counts from the 1st data-set ARE SIMILAR TO the counts from the 2nd data-set" (i.e. null hypothesis), and with the Chi-squared test we explore that hypothesis. If wrong, then: The two-sample Chi-squared test does not make sense and it cannot performed at all for a two-sample comparison.

Your calculation looks wrong to me. You should have a two-way table of observed frequencies with dimension $2 \times $ #bins. Then the expected frequencies are calculated on the assumption that the underlying proportions are just the same.  From earlier comments I carry over (1) even if done correctly your chi-square procedure depends on arbitrary binning (2) the idea that your two distributions of mammal counts (in the original question) are identical seems unlikely to be of biological interest. A quantile-quantile plot of two observed distributions is a better place to start.

Thanks a lot @NickCox, I will follow your suggestions, thanks

I know this must be very frustrating for you but you need to find a middle way between a short question that is not clear enough and a long question that is just too much for most people to read and digest.

Yes, you are right... thanks!

Summarizing the many comments:

The wrong chi-square test was used.
Even with the correct chi-square test, binning data is unwise.
Ties can matter.
Different tests can provide markedly different results.
Comparing distributions this way is probably not the best way to proceed.

Wrong chi-square test
The chi2gof() function from MATLAB, as used here, is NOT the correct chi-square test in this context. That test evaluates whether a particular set of observed counts (the Frequency argument) matches a known probability distribution (the Expected argument).
The (inappropriate) chi-square goodness-of-fit test used in the question treats one observed distribution as the known reference. That's an additional way in which that type of chi-square test differs from the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test and the (more appropriate) contingency table test described below, which treat the two observed distributions symmetrically.
The correct chi-square test with two sets of observed counts is a test on contingency tables. Then the "expected" frequencies used for the test are based on both sets of counts, as the null hypothesis is that they were drawn from the same distribution.
Here's a quick comparison based on the data setup in the question, in R.
set.seed(0,kind="Mersenne-Twister")
a <- 0
b <- 100
r1 <- (b-a) * round(rlnorm(1000,1,1)) + a
r2 <- (b-a) * round(rlnorm(1000,.88,1.1)) + a
## truncate both at values of 2000, as in the question
r1trunc <- r1[r1<=2000]
r2trunc <- r2[r2<=2000]
## put into 20 bins, to match the question
## the results are factors
r1breaks <- cut(r1trunc,breaks=20)
r2breaks <- cut(r2trunc,breaks=20)
## summary() on a factor produces the count for each level
## this is the contingency table test
chisq.test(cbind(summary(r1breaks),summary(r2breaks)))
#
#   Pearson's Chi-squared test
#
# data:  cbind(summary(r1breaks), summary(r2breaks))
# X-squared = 19.959, df = 19, p-value = 0.3971
##
## now reproduce the incorrect "goodness of fit test" with r2 as the "known" probabilities
r2freq <- summary(r2breaks)/length(r2trunc)
## the p argument is the vector of expected probabilities, here based solely on r2
chisq.test(summary(r1breaks),p=r2freq)
#
# Chi-squared test for given probabilities
#
# data:  summary(r1breaks)
# X-squared = 51.36, df = 19, p-value = 8.246e-05
##
## highly "significant," but the wrong test

Binning
Binning a continuous variable is not a good idea. Although the proper chi-square test on the binned data found no significant difference between the two distributions, Wilcoxon and Kolmogorov-Smirnov tests, which use the entire distributions, did.
wilcox.test(r1,r2)
#
#   Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction
#
# data:  r1 and r2
# W = 529108, p-value = 0.02242
# alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0


ks.test(r1,r2)
#
# Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
#
# data:  r1 and r2
# D = 0.061, p-value = 0.04842
# alternative hypothesis: two-sided
#
# Warning message:
# In ks.test(r1, r2) : p-value will be approximate in the presence of ties

Ties
These data aren't continuous, as they were rounded to integer multiples of 100. The twosamples package in R allows for randomization tests that should be more reliable. Reset the random seed for reproducibility and repeat a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test.
library(twosamples)
set.seed(20240815);ks_test(r1,r2)
# Test Stat   P-Value 
#    0.0610    0.0125 

That's the same test statistic but with a smaller p-value, suggesting higher power with this randomization test.
Different tests
These synthetic data are interesting, with identical first and third quartiles, almost identical mean values, but different medians.
summary(r1)
#   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#    0.0   100.0   300.0   444.1   500.0  7100.0 
summary(r2)
#    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#       0     100     200     440     500    6800 

Density plots (on a square root scale) illustrate the difference.
plot(density(sqrt(r1)),bty="n",col="blue",main="Density plots:\nr1, blue; r2, red ",xlab="Square root of counts")
lines(density(sqrt(r2)),bty="n",col="red")


The twosamples package can perform several different tests (with randomization for p-values) that treat the distributions symmetrically. Although the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test (based on the maximum distance between the cumulative distributions) found a difference, the Wasserstein test (based on the "earth-mover" distance) did not.
set.seed(20240815);wass_test(r1,r2)
# Test Stat   P-Value 
#   34.7000    0.3755 

In contrast, Andersen-Darling and Cramér-von Mises tests showed significant differences.
set.seed(20240815);ad_test(r1,r2)
# Test Stat   P-Value 
# 17034.222     0.005 
set.seed(20240815);cvm_test(r1,r2)
# Test Stat   P-Value 
#  2.789831  0.017500 

You have to decide what type of difference matters before you perform this type of test.
Better approaches
Comparing two distributions in this way is very limiting. You only compare two things, without evaluating the specific nature of the differences. In practice there will typically be multiple factors of interest affecting the distributions, which would better be handled by a comprehensive regression or other type of model.

Cool, thanks a lot!

I also found the two-sample Chi-squared test on https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/software/dataplot/refman1/auxillar/chi2samp.htm.
.........but probably, it is different from the contingency table test
chisq.test() you have used, I guess from https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/chisq.test

@Ommo in principle those tests in the two links should be the same, as they are both standard chi-square tests on contingency tables. Implementations of the contingency table chi-square test can differ in things like how they treat cells with small numbers of cases, so read the manual pages carefully. A quick web search suggests that you need the Statistics Toolbox to do a contingency table test in MATLAB. It's built right in to the base distribution of R.

I am really thankful! ...I learn more on this website than on books and articles

Just for information, the Matlab's crosstab() function returns exactly the same values of the R's chisq.test() function (at least for this case!). More details in my question, in Extra content... - Thanks again!

This is excellent, except insofar as it summarizes several but not all the many comments. I want to flag once again that chi-square testing is far from optimal for the underlying problem as it entails binning of the data, which will always be arbitrary and will always lose some of the information in the data. The associated hypothesis that two samples of mammal counts  come from exactly the same distribution may be a straw person null hypothesis, but even if so direct comparison of the distributions -- their similarities and differences -- is more likely to be rewarding scientifically.

@NickCox thanks. You prompted me to expand the answer to address more of what was covered in the comments. It was fun trying the different tests on this data set

I upvoted your excellent answer earlier, but a detail is bothering me. chisq.test(summary(r1breaks),summary(r2breaks)) does not conduct a test on a 2x20 contingency table (as reflected by the output, showing df = 306, i.e. 306 degrees of freedom). If you intended a test on a  2x20 contingency table, I think one should use  chisq.test(cbind(summary(r1breaks),summary(r2breaks))) or chisq.test(rbind(summary(r1breaks),summary(r2breaks))). The code you used is passing summary(r2breaks) to the y parameter, which has a quite specific purpose: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/109605/

@J-J-J you are of course absolutely correct. Replaced my erroneous choice of chi-square test in the answer.

@EdM about the "The wrong chi-squared test was used", it is not very correct. I mean, you can use either "crosstab()" or "chi2gof(...,'freq',observed,'expected',expected)", but treating the inputs slightly differently, and they will return the same results. Please see here for more information: https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/96572-how-can-i-perform-a-chi-square-test-to-determine-how-statistically-different-two-proportions-are-in

@Ommo those functions certainly can be used correctly for chi-square contingency-table tests (as that link documents), but you didn't use the functions that way in the tests that you reported in the question.

Thanks @EdM for your comment :-) ...Well.... What I used, i.e. chi2gof(1:length(h1.Values(1:last_bin)), 'Expected', h2.Values(1:last_bin), 'Frequency', h1.Values(1:last_bin)), i.e. chi2gof between binned counts (derived through the histogram function) is exactly the same as in the mentioned link, i.e. https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/96572-how-can-i-perform-a-chi-square-test-to-determine-how-statistically-different-two-proportions-are-in Maybe, there was some minor option I did not use :-)

@Ommo the chi2gof example on the linked page (the third example) uses a "Pooled estimate of proportions" based on both sets of observed values to get the "expected" counts under the null hypothesis. That is correct. That's not what you did. You just used the observed h2.Values for the "expected" counts. That's not just some "minor option"; it's incorrect pre-processing of the data for using that function to perform a proper chi-square test. It's important to read code very carefully. Don't assume that because the same function was used that it was used in the same way.

A main theme in your recent threads is that (A) comparing a vector of observed frequencies with one of expected frequencies is quite different from )B) comparing two vectors of observed frequencies given a hypothesis that they both arise from the same expected probabilities.
