Chi-square test on contingency tables, with same input for both arguments of the test
If I use the same input for both arguments of the chisq.test (in R), shouldn't I get a p-value equal to 1? I get instead 0.

As I understand it you have a $2 \times 20$ table, so the number of df should be  $1 \times 19 = 19$. Can you show us rlbs which IIUC is a vector of 20 counts?

@NickCox is correct, you misused the chisq.test function, e.g. look what chisq.test(r1bs,r1bs)$observed looks like, and read the documentation of the function. Try chisq.test(cbind(r1bs,r2bs)) instead to pass a contingency table to the function (which is not what you did, but should have done).

In addition, with the method you used to generate your data, it seems that you have several expected counts of zeroes (this is at least what I get on my computer), so you won't get a p-value due to the division by 0 it implies (see the formula of the chi-square statistic).

@NickCox, Yes, a $2 \times 20$ table of binned data, i.e. r1bs and r2bs. Please see them in the question.

As @J-J-J guesses you have some observed counts of 0.  In that case, either the software will drop those bins automatically or the chi-square statistic can't be calculated.  You should not get 100 df either way.

Thanks, yes, I should get $df=20-1=19$

See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/109605/what-does-y-argument-do-in-chisq-test-in-r, it should give you the explanation as to why you did not pass the contingency table you thought you passed to the function (this is reflected in the df = 100 you get).

Small mistake in my first comment by the way, I meant chisq.test(r1bs,r2bs)$observed, not chisq.test(r1bs,r1bs)$observed.

Yes, I used chisq.test(r1bs,r2bs)$observed

Strictly some software might trap $(0 - 0)^2 / 0$ as meaning zero. It's an interesting question what the code should do.  I must check my own small programs in this territory.

We are still at cross purposes here: if you want to check as a limiting case what happens when a vector of counts is compared with itself, the same vector must be fed twice to the software.

You need confirmation from an expert or experienced user of R such as @J-J-J that this is what you need here.

It's the community, not the OP, who decide whether a question is clear and good for the forum. In this case, although misunderstandings and mistakes you made have been identified and clarified, that is the problem with the thread as well as good for you. I doubt that this thread is of much use to anyone else in the future. It needed a lot of discussion to be clear on what you did  and what went wrong. A good question leads immediately and directly to good answer(s).  This really wasn't extremely clear with a super easy example!

@Ommo I'd suggest to ask your question on https://stackoverflow.com, where you'll find a community of R users who may be able to explain in detail where things went wrong with your code. But again, in your case, you shouldn't be using chisq.test(x, y), but chisq.test(cbind(x, y)) in order to pass the 2x20 contingency table to the function.

@J-J-J, thanks, I tried the chisq.test(cbind(r1bs,r2bs)), I get the following:
data:  cbind(r1bs, r2bs), X-squared = NaN, df = 19, p-value = NA ....So the degrees of freedom are correct, but X-squared and p-value are NaN......

@Ommo Yes, the function cannot calculate a chi-square statistic, because you have expected counts of 0 in some cells, as explained in previous comments.

Otherwise, it seems clear that the R code won't ignore and can't do anything given the zero counts. I guess most statistical people would regard that as objective and defensible.

More generally: a negative about SE is that it is not a help line for individuals. It's a forum with a main goal of building up a resource of answered questions that should be of future use to as many people as possible. The questions from you that I've seen all seem to start with a personal puzzle which is only clear after rounds of discussion and revision.  Quite often different people make the same comments again and again. The implication seems to be that you may need to work a bit harder on your questions before you post them in public, e.g.. first try out code with really simple input.

I don't think this is a matter of unwritten rules. What I have said is all documented -- whether you have read it is another matter. Also, it's easy to find out that there is a company behind this, but bizarrely it's not relevant at all. The company pay me nothing and I pay them nothing for what I do here, and the same is I believe true for anyone else who has interacted with you on CV.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour has the essence. In its terms any thread that requires or implies a great deal of discussion is a poor thread.

What the OP is doing will perhaps be clearer from a related thread. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/652702/why-do-i-get-a-large-difference-between-the-p-value-of-a-chi-square-test-and-the  That thread -- like this one -- is long and convoluted with many cycles of revision to the question and lengthy and repetitive series of comments. The net result is that neither thread is likely to be helpful in future to others. The original reason for closing this one is one that still applies to the latest version.

(ctd) It needs a detailed example to be clear. In essence, my answer still has the main story: the wrong function was used (in R) for the OP's problem. Sorry, but I don't feel obliged or tempted to do all the work of inventing examples and showing in detail which R function should be used -- if only because I am not a routine R user in any case. But the principle that comparing identical vectors of observed counts in the circumstance described should indeed yield a test statistic of 0 transcends choice of software -- and is evident from just thinking about the calculation.

If two sets of observed counts (two rows say of a $2 \times k$ contingency table) are exactly equal, then the corresponding expected counts are also equal to them and a chi-square test should yield a test statistic of 0.
Here is a demonstration from Stata (detail for its users: using tabchii from SSC). You should be able to get the same result in R.
. tabchii 1000 100 10 1 \ 1000 100 10 1

          observed frequency
          expected frequency

--------------------------------------------------
          |                  col                  
      row |        1         2         3         4
----------+---------------------------------------
        1 |     1000       100        10         1
          | 1000.000   100.000    10.000     1.000
          | 
        2 |     1000       100        10         1
          | 1000.000   100.000    10.000     1.000
--------------------------------------------------

2 cells with expected frequency < 5

         Pearson chi2(3) =   0.0000   Pr = 1.000
likelihood-ratio chi2(3) =   0.0000   Pr = 1.000

My hypotheses:

You're using the wrong function or feeding it the wrong arguments in R (very high credibility). Others will address this if true.

You're being bitten by some issue with machine calculations given the explosive tendency inherent in $\sum (f - \hat f)^2 / \hat f$ for observed frequencies $f$ and expected frequencies $\hat f$ (low credibility).

You've tickled a bug in R (extraordinarily low credibility).

I've misunderstood what you're doing (higher credibility than #2 or #3).



Thanks @NickCox! Well, if I understood well your Stata code, you use two identical sets of observed counts with $k=4$ elements each one, i.e. 1000  100  10  1, shown in the table's columns 1,2,3, and 4, respectively, and just besides the row numbers 1 and 2. Underneath each set of observed counts, you have the calculated sets of expected counts, i..e 1000.000   100.000    10.000     1.000. Then, by applying the tabchii function from the package tab_chi (SSC), you get the chi-square test on contingency table, resulting in a statistics $= 0$ and a p-value $= 1$. Right?

Quite, except for the pedantic detail that tabchii is a command in Stata, not a function and the less pedantic detail that the expected counts don't exist before tabchii calculates them.
